# How can I aggregate/combine 3 columns of a data frame into one column with the sum of the values of the other three in R?

Tags: r, statistics

[image]

Part of my dataset is shown in this image, I want to combine the columns `GR_S01_w1_a`, `GR_S01_w1_b` and `GR_S01_w1_c` into a single column - `GR_S01_w1` - whose values are the sum of the three.

I know how to use mutate to add a new column which does this, but I also want to delete the other three, and do this about 100 more times for all the other samples I have. So essentially - I have three replicates of each sample in the form of a column of the format `samplename_a`, `samplename_b` and `samplename_c`, and I want to replace these with a single column, many times over.

I have tried using mutate like this -

```r
Gregory <- Gregory %>% mutate(GR_S01_w1 = sum(GR_S01_w1_a, GR_S01_w1_b, GR_S01_w1_c))
```

but for all of the samples that I have this would of course take far too long. Is there a quick way for me to do this (other than manually on excel which is what I'm doing at the moment)?

Comment: The easiest way to automatically do this is probably by first using `gather` to convert the data to a long format. After that create a new column that you can use to make the groups (i.e. convert GR_S01_w1_c to GR_S01_w1_c) and use `groupby`, `mutate`, and `sum` to sum over that new column. Finally, if necessary, you can convert those group back over the columns using `spread`.

Comment: A work around can be to use column numbers. Are your columns strictly in the manner of a,b,c then again a,b,c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

This can be done by following a number of steps:

1. Use `grep` to get the groups of columns to sum over
2. Use `rowSums` over each group of columns

```r
base <- c("GR_S01_w1", "GR_S01_w2")
cols <- lapply(base, grep, names(Gregory), fixed = TRUE)
for (i in seq_along(base)) {
  Gregory[, base[i]] <- rowSums(Gregory[, cols[[i]]])
}
```

This automates the whole process without defining any names manually (apart from the group names), and without having to transform your dataset to long and then back to wide.

---

**Finding the sample names automatically**

If you also don't want to have to specify the samples by hand, then you can use `grep` and `sub`. Here, we make the assumption that your structure is always "sample underscore letter", e.g. `sample_d` or `test_sample_b`. We can do this by using `grep`:

```r
relevant_columns <- grep(".*_[a-zA-Z]{1}$", names(Gregory), value = TRUE)
base <- unique(sub("(_[a-zA-Z]{1})$", "", relevant_columns))
base
# [1] "GR_S01_w1" "GR_S01_w2"
```

What the `grep` term means:

- `.*`: Any number of any characters.
- `_`: Presence of an underscore, followed by...
- `[a-zA-Z]`: Any of the alphabetic letters (lowercase or upper case).
- `{1}`: Only one of those.
- `$`: This is the end of the word.

Next, we just use `sub` to remove that part, select the `unique` values, and we're done.

This does assume that:

1. There are no other columns that end with `_[a-zA-Z]`; you can just avoid those columns by inputting `names(Gregory)[-1]` or whatever columns you DON'T want to consider.
2. Names are only followed by ONE letter, not e.g. two or three.

Comment: Thanks for this slamballais! Seems like there's not really a short cut which allows me to skip the process of specifying the columns I want to group , but maybe I can try this code and substitute the values of base with column numbers instead of column names, to avoid having to type out a hundred detailed column names :)

Comment: I added some code that automatically finds all the unique names in your columns, so that you don't have to type them out.

Comment: Perfect!! Yes this is what I was hoping could be done! THANK YOU :D

Comment: Would you possibly be able to explain the code from the first two steps (grep and rowSums) in a bit more detail so I can troubleshoot my errors? (my R skills are very entry level). At the moment this is the error I'm getting : `> cols <- lapply(base, grep, names(teleZ), fixed = TRUE)
> for (i in seq_along(base)) {teleZ[, base[i]] <- rowSums(teleZ, cols[i])}
Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  invalid 'na.rm' argument`.  (Database name is now teleZ, not Gregory)

Comment: I tried using `lapply` for the last step and there were no errors but the dataset didn't change at all

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the `rowSums` call should be `rowSums(Gregory[, cols[[i]]])`. Also, for debugging: can you check whether `base` contains what you expected? If not, can you give some examples of the names? Next: `cols` should give a list where every entry contains column numbers. Can you check whether `cols` indeed contains those? The best way to debug this is by going step-by-step and making sure that things are happening as you would expect them to.

Comment: `base` is a string of the correct new column names, i.e. without a,b,c at the end. And yep, `cols` is as you described.  I changed the code to what you updated just now but still no luck :( no errors when using `lapply` but also no change in the data frame. Which part of the code tells it to replace the three columns with one?

Comment: Omg wait I just realised. We've added the new columns, and now I just need to delete the old ones! They weren't showing up naturally because there are 400 columns and they got tagged on at the end and cut off in the viewing panel. FANTASTIC.  Thank you so so much for your help, legend :)

Comment: Haha, yes, was gonna say :) In the `for`-loop, you can (probably) delete them by adding the line `Gregory <- Gregory[, -cols[[i]]]` or `Gregory[, cols[[i]]] <- NULL`. Or, for both the `for`-loop and `lapply` you can just do this after the code: `Gregory[, unlist(cols)] <- NULL`. With `unlist`, we "unlist" the list, and we get one big vector. Since we need to remove all columns, we can just do that in one step.

Comment: Last issue, just went through it and I see that it seems to have filled in each new column with the sum of ALL the columns instead of the three that it is replacing. So the values of all the new columns are identical. Do you know what needs tweaking for that?

Comment: That's odd, it works in a toy example (just checked). Can you try from scratch again? If that doesn't help, does `cols` contain every column in every entry, or are there only 3-ish columns per entry? If that's the case, I'm actually not sure where it could be going wrong. In theory, when we use `rowSums(Gregory[, cols[[i]]])` it just fills in those columns, so for example `rowSums(Gregory[, c(2, 3, 4)])`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126210/discussion-between-aashi-and-slamballais).

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can do this quite easily with:

```
# creates new variable as sum of the 3 existing ones
data$GR_S01_w1 <- data$GR_S01_w1_a + data$GR_S01_w1_b + data$GR_S01_w1_c

# remove the 3 existing ones
data$GR_S01_w1_a <- data$GR_S01_w1_b <- data$GR_S01_w1_c <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! This helps for the one set of columns, but to replicate that step across another hundred samples (typing out each sample name) is rather too much effort.... Maybe it's just something that can't really be automated, ended up doing it in Excel :)